# Using Cider on Android

Tags: android, clojure, leiningen, cider

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/alexander-yakushev/events/blob/master/tutorial.md) on `lein-droid`-based Clojure development on Android. However, the tutorial skips on setting up Cider support.

I start with a default `lein-droid` project by adding

```
:user {:plugins [ [lein-droid "0.4.0-alpha4"] ]}
```

to my `~/.lein/profiles.clj`, and then run

```
$ lein droid new android-hello com.example.android_hello
```

According to the tutorial, I should be able to do a `lein droid doall` and then connect with Cider to `localhost:9999` at this point; however, it is unusable because of nREPL missing on the Android side:

```
; CIDER 0.9.1 (Java 0, Clojure 1.7.0-beta3-r2, nREPL nil)
WARNING: CIDER's version (0.9.1) does not match cider-nrepl's version (not installed)
```

So then, according to [this other tutorial](https://github.com/clojure-android/lein-droid/wiki/Tutorial) that I've found, I should add `cider-nrepl` to my Android dependencies by adding this to `~/.lein/profiles.clj`:

```
:android-user {:plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.9.1"]]
                :android {:aot-exclude-ns ["cider.nrepl.middleware.util.java.parser"
                                           "cider.nrepl" "cider-nrepl.plugin"]}}}
```

So I do a new `lein clean; lein droid doall` to make sure everything is picked up nicely; and now the resulting program crashes on Android at startup:

```
W/dalvikvm( 2508): Exception Ljava/lang/IllegalArgumentException; thrown while initializing Ldeps/cljfmt/v0v1v10/cljfmt/core__init;
W/dalvikvm( 2508): Exception Ljava/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError; thrown while initializing Lcider/nrepl/middleware/format__init;
W/dalvikvm( 2508): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb5157180)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508): FATAL EXCEPTION: ClojureLoadingThread
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2201)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2229)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:461)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:437)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$load$fn__5442.invoke(core.clj:5858)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5857)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5663)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5391.invoke(core.clj:5703)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5702)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5741)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5824)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at neko.tools.repl$start_repl$fn__6556$fn__6557.invoke(repl.clj:77)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$map$fn__4547.invoke(core.clj:2616)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:534)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$seq__4122.invoke(core.clj:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:628)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at neko.tools.repl$start_repl$fn__6556.invoke(repl.clj:75)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$with_redefs_fn.invoke(core.clj:7185)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at neko.tools.repl$start_repl.doInvoke(repl.clj:72)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at neko.tools.repl$init.doInvoke(repl.clj:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:375)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at neko.App.loadClojure(App.java:40)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at neko.App$1.run(App.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2201)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2229)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:461)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:437)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$load$fn__5442.invoke(core.clj:5858)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5857)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5663)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5391.invoke(core.clj:5703)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5702)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5741)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5824)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:703)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at cider.nrepl.middleware.format$loading__5334__auto____6889.invoke(format.clj:1)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at cider.nrepl.middleware.format__init.load(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at cider.nrepl.middleware.format__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    ... 38 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :make-reader of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/IOFactory found for class: nil
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$_cache_protocol_fn.invoke(core_deftype.clj:554)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.java.io$fn__8970$G__8946__8977.invoke(io.clj:69)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.java.io$reader.doInvoke(io.clj:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$slurp.doInvoke(core.clj:6645)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$comp$fn__4489.invoke(core.clj:2432)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at clojure.core$comp$fn__4489.invoke(core.clj:2432)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at deps.cljfmt.v0v1v10.cljfmt.core__init.load(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    at deps.cljfmt.v0v1v10.cljfmt.core__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2508):    ... 61 more
W/ActivityManager(  867):   Force finishing activity hu.erdi.gergo.clojure_android_hello.debug/hu.erdi.gergo.clojure_android_hello.SplashActivity
W/WindowManager(  867): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
D/dalvikvm(  867): GC_CONCURRENT freed 561K, 13% free 11324K/12871K, paused 0ms+2ms
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(  867): setKernelCountSet(10041, 0) failed with errno -2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you made a small mistake when following the tutorial you referenced above.

This:

```
:android-user {:plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.9.1"]]
                :android {:aot-exclude-ns ["cider.nrepl.middleware.util.java.parser"
                                           "cider.nrepl" "cider-nrepl.plugin"]}}}
```

Should be:

```
:android-user {:dependencies [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.9.1"]]
               :android {:aot-exclude-ns ["cider.nrepl.middleware.util.java.parser"
                                          "cider.nrepl" "cider-nrepl.plugin"]}}
```